# Translating strings to English from a second language

Tags: 7, i18n-l10n

It seems that Drupal 7 doesn't provide a function to translate a non-English string to its English equivalent. I'd like to do this for a project I'm working on, but the absence of a reverse-translation function suggests that perhaps I shouldn't. Is there any reason for the absence of a function that translates strings back to English? And how should I achieve this functionality with my project?

Comment: `ping -R -c 1` :) Check out my answer please. Feel free to ask questions or add details to your question.

Answer (score 2):

## `t()` function

By Drupal architecture English is a system built-in language which is used as a **source language** in code.
`t()` function allows to translate from system language to any other language. It is simple and expected behavior.

## UI

There are UI improvements in Drupal 8: http://hojtsy.hu/blog/2013-aug-20/drupal-8-multilingual-tidbits-12-english-can-now-be-translated

Comment about Drupal 7 "Custom English" and problems with default language:

> Using Drupal core alone, this was possible to achieve in Drupal 7 by
>   configuring a "Custom English" language on the site with a language
>   code different from "en", which then allowed you to replace text with
>   your choosing. This quickly gets confusing though because then both
>   the old "en" English language and your new "Custom English" will show
>   up in language selectors, etc. If you disable the "en" English, then
>   your old content saved with that langcode will not display properly.
>   Its a whole can of worms. You may also use String overrides, but if
>   you are using interface translation from core anyway, using one more
>   module for the same task for a specific language is overkill.

## i18n features

More complex translation features (like Content translation from core or [i18n](https://drupal.org/project/i18n) package) less depend on system language but often depend on *default* language. Usually you can add content piece in any language and then translate it to English without any problems.

## Summary

- In code use English only and translate it to other languages in UI.
- Select *default* language once and do not change it.
- For changing built-in English strings check out “Translating English strings” section in this article: http://www.packtpub.com/article/setting-basics-drupal-multilingual-site-languages-ui-translation ([String Overrides](https://drupal.org/project/stringoverrides) / Custom English / settings.php)
- Discover [i18n](https://drupal.org/project/i18n) package tools.